# Remove addthis random characters from url

Tags: addthis

I use addthis widget. When I go throughout my webpages I get random characters in the end of the url.

I removed them by setting `{"data_track_addressbar":false}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
```

If I do so, what does it mean? Does this influence some how to the addthis. In any case I could not keep the random characters, as the customer do not want to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics):

> Address bar share tracking works by appending a special tag to your
>   URL once your page has loaded. Your URLs will start to look like this:
>
> http://example.com/blog#AHb4gs1hwck
>
> In this case, "#AHb4gs1hwck" is a semi-random value which identifies
>   each page view. When a user clicks on an URL like this we'll know that
>   they were the recipient of an address bar share and we'll count a
>   share and a click for your site.

If you disable this feature, you'll lose whatever analytics are being generated by uniquely identifying each page view. If that data matters to you/your customer, you'll need to leave the feature enabled (or find another tracking solution).